# How do I get a keyIterator for a LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, iterator, linkedhashmap

By looking at the source code for LinkedHashMaps from Sun, I see that there is a private class called KeyIterator, I would like to use this. How can I gain access?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You get it by calling

```
myMap.keySet().iterator();
```

You shouldn't even need to know it exists; it's just an artifact of the implementation. For all you know, they could be using flying monkeys to iterate the keys; as long as they're iterated according to the spec, it doesn't matter how they do it.

By the way, did you know that `HashMap` has a private class called `KeyIterator` (as do `ConcurrentHashMap`, `ConcurrentSkipListMap`, `EnumMap`, `IdentityHashMap`, `TreeMap`, and `WeakHashMap`)?
Does that make a difference in how you iterate through the keys of a `HashMap`?

---

**Edit:** In reponse to your comment, be aware that if you are trying to iterate over all *key-value pairs* in a `Map`, there is a better way than iterating over the keys and calling `get` for each. The [`entrySet()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()) method gets a `Set` of all key-value pairs which you can then iterate over. So instead of writing:

```
for (Key key : myMap.keySet()) {
    Value val = myMap.get(key);
    ...
}
```

you should write:

```
for (Map.Entry<Key, Value> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
    doSomethingWithKey(entry.getKey());
    doSomethingWithValue(entry.getValue());
    ...
}
```

You could also iterate over the values with [`values()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()) if you want.

Note that since `keySet`, `entrySet`, and `values` are defined in the [`Map` interface](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), they will work for any `Map`, not just `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: It just didn't occur to me that I could iterate over a LinkedHashMap until I saw the internal private class. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: I didn't know what use is entrySet() of. But, its really useful in almost all places i use a HashMap.
Thanks @Michael

Answer (score 4):

It's a private class, so you can't directly use it.

```
  private class KeyIterator extends LinkedHashIterator<K> {
```

An instance of it is returned when you use the normal Iterator.

```
myMap.keySet().iterator()
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use anything that is defined as part of the internal implementation of LinkedHashMap (i.e. in the source code but not defined in the API). What happens if the internal implementation changes in the next release? All of your code using it will break.

You should code to the [API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) and do something like

```
myMap.keySet().iterator()
```