# How I can get key, value pair from LinkedHashMap iterator?

Tags: java, iterator, linkedhashmap

I test SnakeYAML library to read .yaml documents. I have read Example 2.27. Invoice from http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/ and I get object:

```
System.out.println(content);
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
Object o = yaml.load(content);
```

where content is String loaded from file using Files.readAllBytes, encoding.decode (encoding is StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

Reflection gaves me that o is type of java.util.LinkedHashMap and I can iterate over them:

```
Set entrySet = o.entrySet();
Iterator it = entrySet.iterator();
System.out.println("LinkedHashMap entries : ");
while (it.hasNext())
{
    Object entry = it.next();
    System.out.println(entry);
}
```

Reflection return that type of entry is LinkedHashMap$Entry. But is **problem**: internal class LinkedHashMap$Entry is private and I can't declare objects this type.
How I can get  pair from entry, iterator or entrSet?

Comment: Use the public interface instead.

Answer (score 6):

You should declare a `Map.Entry` rather than the `LinkedHashMap.Entry`:

```
while (it.hasNext())
{
    Map.Entry<?,?> entry = it.next();
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    System.out.println(entry.getValue());
}
```

`Map.Entry` is the `public interface`, `LinkedHashMap.Entry` is a private implementation of that interface.

Notice that I also declare the `Entry` with `<?,?>`, this is a [generic declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). If you know the type of the `Map` you can declare that type and you won't need to cast:

```
Set<Entry<?,?>> entrySet = o.entrySet();
Iterator<Entry<?,?>> it = entrySet.iterator();
```

Further you can use an enhanced foreach loop to iterate:

```
final Map<?,?> myMap = (Map<?,?>) yaml.load(content);
for(final Entry<?,?> entry : o.entrySet()) {
    //do stuff with entry
}
```

Obviously if you know your `Map` is mapping `String` to `Object` (for example) you could use `Map<String, Object>`

Answer (score 1):

Check out the examples posted at: 
[Java - The LinkedHashMap Class](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_linkedhashmap_class.htm) and 
[How do I get a keyIterator for a LinkedHashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978200/how-do-i-get-a-keyiterator-for-a-linkedhashmap)